# Decode vs Joining Table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query similar to below , where In I join a few tables to get the required data. I explicitly join two tables (`TableA` and `TableB` , so that later I can put a where condition on `TableB`

I was wondering which of the below options uses less resources .i.e, has better performance and hence faster ?

**Approach 1**

```
            SELECT
                TB.Column1,
                --Other Columns
            FROM 
               TableA TA
               INNER JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.Column1= TB.Column2)
              -- Some other Joins
            Where 
               TB.Column1 in ("Option1", "Option2"........,"Option12")
```

**Approach 2**

```
         SELECT
              DECODE(TA.Column1, 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'Option1',
                    'BBBBBBBBBBBB', 'Option2',
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    'LLLLLLLLLLLLLL','Option12'),
             --Other Columns
         FROM 
               TableA TA
              -- Some other Joins
         WHERE TA.Column1 in ('AAAAAAAAAAAA',....,'LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL')
```

I have checked the query timings in Toad , the results are confusing . For smaller dataset Approach 2 seems to be performing better , but for larger dataset Approach 1 is faster.

Comment: This will depend on how DECODE is implemented.  Clearly the Approach 1 is considered a leading practice.

Comment: If you want to get to the bottom of it you need to observe and understand the query plan. Often Oracle (and most databases) can optimise table joins better than hard-coded IN statements, meaning approach 1 is probably better. Regardless of performance it's generally better practice to put data into a table, and not hard code into SQL logic, so that's another reason to go with option 1. But you need to check the query plan to be certain.

Comment: @ElectricLlama Thanks that was very informative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best performance I suggest the following:

1. If TB.Column1 only contains the values you are interested in then remove the where clause, the inner join will filter for you.
2. If not then add boolean column to tb (eg MySelectFlag) set it to 1 for those items in this query then your join becomes

   ```
   INNER JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.Column1= TB.Column2) AND TB.MySelectFlag = 1
   ```

This will be quite fast (esp. if you add an index to TB.MySelectFlag)

Comment: TB.Column1 has numerous valus , but I am interested in only 12 items out of those. I am not allowed to modify the existing table. I can create a new table which only has values I want , would that be something you would recommend?

Comment: If MySelectFlag contains only 0 and 1 then it is not selective and the index probably won't be used.

Comment: @misguided -- if you only have 12 items then use decode if it is faster -- downside is you can't modify the table to change behavior... but you can't anyway.